# If pointer stores the address of a variable and is itself a variable, doesn't it create infinite pointers and fills the entire system memory?

Tags: c, pointers

Here's one more problem with pointers :

How is printing something or not influencing the value stored at a particular address?

l-k has a value equal to 1, that's why i'm checking if the value stored at k+1 is equal to 88 or not.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int i=55;
    int j=88;
    int *k=&i;
    int *l=&j;
    k++;
//  printf("%p\n",l-k); 
/*  Why does uncommenting previous line changes the output from 0 to 88?  */
    printf("%i",*k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`k++` invokes Undefined Behaviour](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8): "If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of **the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object**, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined**."

Comment: @pmg `k++` is not UB - the result is 1-past the object, whih is ok. `*k` afterwarrds is.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I interpret the Standard as saying `k++` is UB, and I agree that if UB hasn't already happenned by the time of `*k`, then *that* is UB :)

Comment: @pmg Or you are saying it is not an *array* object? Interesting question - can `&i` be considered as a pointer to array of one element?

Comment: *Very interesting*! I often do `sometype foo[1];` myself !!

Comment: @pmg, the side effect of the postfix `++` operator on the value of its operand is explicitly defined in terms of the behavior of the infix `+` operator when the operand is a pointer.  And in that case, "a pointer to an object that is not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type." ([C2011, 6.5.6/7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p7)).  There is nothing undefined about the behavior of the expression `k++` in the OP's code.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for this reference. It have covered this hole...

Comment: Thank you @JohnBollinger. Right in front of my eyes and I missed that

Comment: `<iostream>` is not a valid C header. Maybe you wanted C++ tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the question in the title:

> If pointer stores the address of a variable and is itself a variable, doesn't it create infinite pointers and fills the entire system memory?

No. I added some code to dump the addresses and contents of each of `i`, `j`, `k`, and `l`, and here is the result:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee31d3a48   37   00   00   00    7...

          j  0x7ffee31d3a44   58   00   00   00    X...

          k  0x7ffee31d3a38   48   3a   1d   e3    H:..
             0x7ffee31d3a3c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

          l  0x7ffee31d3a30   44   3a   1d   e3    D:..
             0x7ffee31d3a34   fe   7f   00   00    ....
```

Hopefully the output is self-explanatory - each row shows the name of the item, its address, and its contents (both in hex and as a sequence of bytes).

I'm on a little-endian system, so multi-byte objects have to be read from bottom to top, right to left.

Anyway, `i` lives at address `0x7ffee31d3a48` and stores the value `55` (`0x37`).  `k` lives at address `0x7ffee31d3a38` and stores the value `0x7ffee31d3a48`, which is the address of `i`.

There's no infinite regression of addresses.  `k` is *just another variable* - the only difference between it and `i` is that it stores a different type of value.

As for your other question:

> Why does uncommenting previous line changes the output from 0 to 88?

The expression `k++` changes what `k` points to - it's no longer pointing to `i`.  Here's the state of the program after that expression:

```
       Item         Address   00   01   02   03
       ----         -------   --   --   --   --
          i  0x7ffee31d3a48   37   00   00   00    7...

          j  0x7ffee31d3a44   58   00   00   00    X...

          k  0x7ffee31d3a38   4c   3a   1d   e3    L:..
             0x7ffee31d3a3c   fe   7f   00   00    ....

          l  0x7ffee31d3a30   44   3a   1d   e3    D:..
             0x7ffee31d3a34   fe   7f   00   00    ....
```

Instead of storing the address of `i` (`0x7ffee31d3a48`), `k` now stores the address `0x7ffeee31d3a4c`, which is ... not the address of any object in your program.  At this point, attempting to dereference `k` invokes *undefined behavior* - your code may crash, or you may get unexpected output, or through some miracle you may get the result you expect.  Removing the `printf` statement changes the layout of your program in memory, which will affect what `k` points to after the `k++` expression.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst

```
k++;
```

is allowed (you are allowed to set a pointer one past the address of a scalar *and* read that pointer value), the behaviour of the subsequent *dereference* of `k` is *undefined*. Somewhat paradoxically that means that the behaviour of your entire program is undefined.

The behaviour of `l-k` would also be undefined. Pointer arithmetic, including the difference between two pointers, is only defined within arrays. For this purpose an object can be regarded as a single element array.

Comment: But here l-k is always coming out to be 1, doesn't that mean that the value at k+1 is the value at l? And the output is 88 when i simply print the value of l-k in the previous line. Why so?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's undefined behavior. This here:

```
k++;
```

Increases the pointer so it points to a different memory location, it advances it by the size of an `int`. If `i` were an array of multiple ints, it would point to the next one in line. But it isn't, so reading from this pointer in the print later is undefined behavior and it might read from an unspecified place.

When I try this program in MSVC, it doesn't print `0` or `88`, it prints `-858993460` every time. A different compiler may print something entirely else, something that changes, or just crash the program, or even do something different than all of those.

Comment: For clarity: `k++` is not UB, the following `*k` is UB.

Comment: That's right. I reworded it a bit to emphasize that the undefined action is reading from the increased value, not the increment itself.

Answer (score 0):

If uncommenting a line affects the output, it seems likely that your code has undefined behaviour. Which is clear from actually reading the code, especially these two lines.

This line is fine.

```
int *k=&i;
```

But what do you expect this line to do?

```
k++;
```

`i` is a single `int` so pointing `k` at the `int` after it has no meaning or use as you could be accessing any part of memory as evident by the fact that sometimes you get 0 or sometimes get 88.